# How can I upgrade npm if npm is broken?

Tags: npm

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and installed npm via the automatic script and it installed 1.1.17. I am now getting the following error message when trying to install anything via npm: "npm ERR! TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings" I found a post stating a solution to my problem is to upgrade to 1.2.15 however I cannot figure out how to do that as updating via npm is throwing an error. How can I update npm without using npm?

Comment: what "automatic script"? yum? apt-get? something else?

Comment: Initially I used apt-get to install it along with node but it was broken so I attempted to upgrade via the automatic installation script at http://npmjs.org/install.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstall node and reinstall to fix this problem.